# How to pass html tags with template variable in django?

Tags: python, django

I try to pass some html tags in server side to front side.

I had programmed like this:

view.py

```
....
context['tags'] = "<div><h1> Hello </h1></div>"
return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

test.html is below:

```
<body>
    {{ tags }}
</body>
```

the rendering result is,

```
<div><h1> Hello </h1></div>
```

But, what I want is

```
<h1> Hello </h1>
```

How do I do? I have to in this way.

```
"<div><h1> {{ tags }} </h1></div>" is not what I want.
```

Comment: Can I ask why you need the html tags in there? There isn't really a way to distinguish what html tags you do want and which ones you don't but I get the feeling this is an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Don't wrap the H1 with a DIV then...?

Comment: In my case, If there is some specific tag, I want to make force to prevent some jquery action.

Answer (score 3):

Use **safe** templatetag: {{ tags|safe }} Here is a link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Update because of the comments:

If I didn't get your question and you wanted to just remove the `div` tag just use templatefilter **removetags**: `{{ tags|removetags:"div" }}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#removetags BUT NOTE it's deprecated since Django 1.8 I recommend you read the reasons and rethink what you want to do...

Comment: If you don't put the `div` in the string it won't render... ( context['tags'] = "<h1> Hello </h1>" )

Comment: Yes, but given the OP'S given input, how will the `safe` template tag help at all

Comment: I am not a mind reader but I think he asks if there is a way the string renders as html...

Comment: "the rendering result is, `<div><h1> Hello </h1></div>` But, what I want is `<h1> Hello </h1>`"